# SimpleCursorAdapter for ListView?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, listview, simplecursoradapter

in my app i need to use the SimpleCursorAdapter for my listview which is being populated by an string[] or ArrayList[]...

i tried the following code:

```
ArrayList<String> mDisplay = new ArrayList<String>();
Cursor c = (Cursor) mDisplay.iterator();
    lv_contactlist.setAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, c ,new String[]{mDisplay.toString()}, new int[]{android.R.id.text1}));
```

but show me error as follows:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListIterator
>   at com.kpj4s.way2sms.ContactsList.onCreate(ContactsList.java:62)
>   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1586)

i think that the Cursor object "c" is not properly set

can any one help me with the code or show me the alternative (note: i need to use only SimpleCursorAdapter)

thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Cursor` is usually the result of a database query.  You are not querying a database and an `Iterator` is not a `Cursor`, hence the `ClassCastException`.

If you are hoping to query a ContentProvider to collect the Contact information see the section "Querying a Content Provider"  at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

If you really only want to display your `ArrayList<String>` try `ArrayAdapter`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html

Comment: Having just gone through the pain of trying (and failing) to make an ArrayAdapter behave the way the docs say it's supposed to do, you may wish to pour yourself a few stiff drinks before you start, though.